# how set a oninput with minlength

Tags: javascript, validation

How can I put a input with a `oninput` that only works when I have a `minlength` defined?

```html
<input type="text" class="password2" id="password" name="password" minlength="8" oninput="myFunction()"><br><br>
```

Comment: It would be nice to clarify the question first. We are seeing answers when the question is not clear. Is it that you want myFunction to be called only if minlength attribute is defined?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to run some code only when your `minlength="8"` is satisfied.

You can check if the input is correctly validated using the `validity` object. It contains the state of all the validation flags. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState

```html
<p id="demo"></p>


<input type="text" class="password2" id="password" name="password" minlength="8" oninput="myFunction(this)"><br><br>

<script>
function myFunction(el) {
    // Check if input is tooShort
    if (el.validity.tooShort) {
        // You can just leave this empty
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Too Short"  
    } else {
        // Run this code if minlength is satisfied
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = el.value;
    }
}
</script>
```

---

You could however also just check the length of the value like this:

```html
<p id="demo"></p>


<input type="text" class="password2" id="password" name="password" minlength="8" oninput="myFunction(this)"><br><br>

<script>
function myFunction(el) {
    // Check if value is at least 8 characters....
    if (el.value.length < 8) {
        // You can just leave this empty
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Too Short"  
    } else {
        // Run this code if length is at least 8
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = el.value;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

read attribute value using `this.getAttribute` method and then relatively call function

`<input type="text" class="password2" id="password" name="password" minlength="8" oninput="this.getAttribute('minlength') !== undefined ? myFunction() : null">`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:
html: `<input type="text" minlength="3" id="input">`
Javascript:

```
let val = document.querySelector("#input");
  val.addEventListener('input', () => {
  let vaLength = document.querySelector("#input").value
  if(vaLength.length >= 5){
    console.log("the input has more than 4 character...")
  }
})
```